# Entering marks for 100 students without making 100 entry boxes

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a project regarding marks details of a class. I want to add marks of 100 students. But I don't want to make 100 entry boxes for that. Is there a good solution for that?
If there is no other way then please tell how to make 100 entryboxes in a loop.[image: This the format of the text file]

Comment: Perhaps you can use a single entry box and fill in the mark per person?

Comment: @TimStack suggestion is one way. even u cud make 100 entry boxes in a loop but wat do u want to do with the data

Comment: I have a text file containing students names. I will enter marks of each student in entryboxes and when i will click submit button, the marks should be appended against each student in the text file.

Comment: you can actually have one entry box and keep on filling it in a loop

Comment: Can you please share the code for that?

Comment: If you have a text file with all the necessary information, why would you even bother doing this by hand? Just write some code that will take all the information from that file

Comment: @TimStack bro, i am not trying to take information from a text file. Instead i want to add something to it!

Comment: Right I see, I misread

Comment: the loop would actually depend upon the way the data in the txt file is formatted, could you put an example your txt file with the Q

Comment: @Cool Cloud do you want to know the format of the text file?

Comment: yes, like how to text is written

Comment: @Cool Cloud for simplicity i have just enter 3 students but actually there will be up to 100 students

Comment: which is the marks?

Comment: the numbers after the names are the marks..... This is just to show you the format of the file....

Comment: so there are 4 marks for each student?

Comment: These marks have nothing to do with what i am asking. The thing i just want is to add more marks in front of each student. For example if add 10 for first student, 10 should be appended after the number 7.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219663/discussion-between-adnan-akram-and-cool-cloud).

Comment: you cant just keep on adding marks, like one student has fixed 5 marks nly?

Comment: No there should be no limit...

Comment: it actually makes no sense? you are telling that there is no limit for a students subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making one entry box for marks and second for student's name. One 'Submit' button below. Then after writing all info in entry boxes, on button press put it in dictionary like: {'Student': mark}
So u will have one dict with all 100 marks for 100 students
Ask if there is smth u don't understand

Comment: But i already have a text file containing students names. I want the marks to get append in the text file against each student when i click submit button.

Comment: I'd better not do it via .txt files. Suppose it's too complicated

Comment: Better google some task similar to your and watch how they've done it